# removal of lines script however struggling with out of range

Tags: python

I am trying to make a python script which first creates a file if it doesnt exist then it creates file with 3 lines and then I am writing a script that if delete line by line however I was getting range error out of index however then I tried to make if statement that if lines are less then < 1 then print error that there is no line however its not working. I am rookie programmer of python and just started 2 days and I wrote the whole code my self and hoping for help. kindly assist on where I am going wrong.

```
import os # importing the os module.

current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
lines = [];
x = [];
remainingline = [];

SHA256_HASHES_pack1 = (current_dir + 'SHA256-Hashes_pack1.txt')

if os.path.exists(SHA256_HASHES_pack1):
    viruslist1 = open(SHA256_HASHES_pack1, "r")
    print(viruslist1.read())
    print("file already exisits")
    
else:
    viruslist1 = open(SHA256_HASHES_pack1, "w")
    viruslist1.write('''line 1
line 2
line 3''')
    viruslist1.close()
    print("i have wrote the file")




for line in lines:
    viruslist1 = open(SHA256_HASHES_pack1, "r")
    lines = viruslist1.readlines()
    viruslist1.close()
    if len(line) < 1:
            del lines[0]
            viruslist1 = open(SHA256_HASHES_pack1, "w+")
            viruslist1.write(line)
            viruslist1.close()
    else:
        print("no line is avaliable")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for-loop does nothing because it loops the empty list `lines` that you define at the beginning of the script. Rather than looping this empty list, you'd want to read the lines from the file first before processing them.

```
with open(SHA256_HASHES_pack1, "r") as viruslist1:
    lines = viruslist1.readlines()

    if lines: # I assume you mean to check if the list is not empty
        del lines[0]
        viruslist1 = open(SHA256_HASHES_pack1, "w+")
        viruslist1.write(''.join(lines)) # turns list into a string again before writing
        viruslist1.close()
    else:
        print("no line is avaliable")
```

Comment: thank you for this. I really appreciate this. like I said I wasn't too sure how not do that without loop but now I understand that its reoccurring the deleting process which is letting the loop to delete twice and which generates the error. can you explain 1 thing how have you enable it to track if no line is left as I don't understand function how is the script catching that there is nothing in list now it can print no line is available as I thought there should be range of items in the list. kindly explain

Comment: No, your original code actually looped the empty list `lines = []` that you define at the top of the script. Meaning it looped nothing, the code in the for-loop wan't executed at all. Point is that you don't need to loop. First read the file, then process the lines that you define in reference to the read file.

Comment: `if lines` will return `True` if the list is not empty, so the code will execute if there is at least 1 line in the file. Otherwise it will print the statement under `else`

Comment: but where have you made if true or false? was it done using the line if lines: does : mean true or false?

Comment: I haven't made anything true or false. `If` is a [conditional](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp) statement that is true if the condition is met, so `if lines` is true if the list `lines` is not empty, i.e. if there is at least one item in the variable `lines`